# Save and retrieve DHTML page in database

Tags: php, database, dhtml

I have a webpage which uses extensive javascript for re-sizing, drag-drop, dynamic content generation, file upload etc. etc. 
So now the question is I am able to successfully save the entire HTML  tag in database, however, when I retrieve and replace the content of current body with new one (the one retrieved from database) all the dynamic properties of content are gone.
Is there any way to preserve all the dynamic properties of page.
p.s. I am not saving JS or CSS as it stays static on server.

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "all dynamic properties are gone" ? How does the rendered html source look like?

Comment: with that I mean I cannot re-size or drag and drop any image, video or whatever I have in there. The source remains the same as I dumped the entire content of HTML body in database. But somehow, everything becomes static.

Comment: If it's written on a file, or echod on the fly on the page it should not make any difference. I was wondering if you had, for example, backslashes after double quotes in your html after retrieving it, that's why I asked how the RENDERED source looks like (not what you save)

Comment: good question, rendered source looks exactly the same the original. for e.g. If I resized a image and dragged it to the bottom of page and saved the entire page and then retrieved it, the image size and position remain the same, however, I cannot re-size or drag it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that all of the interactions are triggered by the user.

for example: 
instate of $(document).ready(); use $(element).hover();

and if that isn't a option than you could always reload the page.

Comment: I really appreciate your reply, but I don't think you get my issue. My issue is that all the events are working perfectly, now I save the page in database, and then I retrieve it, now everything is rendered correctly as the way it was, but the dynamic parts stop working, like I cannot drag and resize images anymore and this page is supposed to have any type user added content. I could be audio, video, image, table etc.

Comment: do you add the html with javascript or php.

Comment: I added the rendered HTML body, and the entire body was rendered using javascript and PHP both

Comment: I believe reloading just the javascript and CSS of the page after I put in content should help(not sure though). But again I have no idea how to do it